# Make cannot find rule to make target

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to take some source files, create some customised versions of those sources, then process those customised sources down to output files I can use. I'm using this make file. Note that this file is not fully complete, currently it only does the CSS* make, once that's working I will add the PHP* make which is similar:

```sh
# root sources
CSSSOURCES =    $(wildcard *.scss)
PHPSOURCES =    $(wildcard *.phtml)

# partials, creates a configed source
CSSMSOURCES =   $(addprefix m.,$(CSSSOURCES:.scss=.m)) 
CSSDSOURCES =   $(addprefix d.,$(CSSSOURCES:.scss=.d)) 
PHPMSOURCES =   $(addprefix m.,$(PHPSOURCES:.phtml=.m)) 
PHPDSOURCES =   $(addprefix d.,$(PHPSOURCES:.phtml=.d))

# targets
CSSMTARGETS =   $(CSSMSOURCES:.m=.css)
CSSDTARGETS =   $(CSSDSOURCES:.d=.css)
PHPMTARGETS =   $(PHPMSOURCES:.m=.php)
PHPDTARGETS =   $(PHPDSOURCES:.d=.php)

# ensure no clash with built in rules
.SUFFIXES: .m .d .scss .css .phtml .php

all:    $(CSSMTARGETS)

%.m:    %.scss
    echo "%define MOBILE" | cat - $< >tmp
    mv tmp $@

%.d:    %.scss
    echo "%define DESKTOP" | cat - $< >tmp
    mv tmp $@

%.css:  %.m %d
    cat $< | mym1.pl >$@
    rm $<

.PHONY: test
test:
    @echo "sources - $(CSSSOURCES)"
    @echo "msources - $(CSSMSOURCES)"
    @echo "targets - $(CSSMTARGETS)"
```

Instead of creating the CSS targets I get this error:

`make: *** No rule to make target 'm.page.css', needed by 'all'.  Stop.`

Comment: Got the '%.css' rule to work on m.page.css you need m.page.m and m.page.d. However, note that the command also remove the input file (rm $<)'.

Comment: The "rm $<" is about cleaning up the intermediate .m and .d files after the css has been created, if I comment this out I still get the same error message

Comment: So fo you have a file `m.page.scss`?

Comment: I have a file page.scss (source) which make should turn into m.page.m and m.page.d (intermediate file via %.m and %.d rules) which make should then turned into m.page.css and d.page.css (targets via %.css rule)

Comment: But there are no recipes in your Makefile which do this. If you need a target `m.page.m` to exist, you need to tell `make` how it should be made.

Comment: My logic (which could be wrong) was that to make the m.page.css target make would look for m.page.m (the %.css: %.m %.d rule), would not find it, so using the %.m: %.scss rule make would make m.page.m from page.css first

Comment: I'm guessing you are looking for a way to create `{m,d}.{a,b,c,d}.css` from sources `a.scss`, `b.scss`, `c.scss`, `d.scss` and correspondingly `.html` from `.phtml` but this is not really clear from the question. Could you please [edit] to clarify?

Comment: Writing to a `tmp` file and then moving to `$@` separately is brittle and prevents parallel `make`. If you need this, don't use a static file name `tmp`; but here, really, I don't think there is any useful way for `cat` to fail where `cat` + `mv` succeeds, so probably just don't use a temporary file.

Comment: Not keen on a tmp file myself but its all I could come up with...you are correct, Im trying to "create {m,d}.{a,b,c,d}.css from sources a.scss, b.scss, c.scss, d.scss and correspondingly .php from .phtml", I tried to say this in the first couple of lines of the post, apologies if I was not clear. How would you do this via make?

Comment: I agree with the comment about static TMP. Usually, the solution that can be used is: create-output > $@.tmp && mv $@.tmp $@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`make` operates on file names; if there is no file named `m.page.m` and no file named `m.page.d` - which is what `m.page.css` depends on in accordance with your declared dependencies - then Make will conclude that it needs to create these. If it does not have any rules (built-in or by way of a recipe) to create those, the error message you get tells you pretty much exactly that.

I'm guessing what you actually want is something like

```
m.%: %
    echo "%define MOBILE" | cat - $< >$@

d.%: %
    echo "%define DESKTOP" | cat - $< >$@
```

This tells `make` how to create `m.whatever` and `d.whatever` from `whatever`; so it now knows how to create `m.x.phtml` from `x.phtml` and `d.y.scss` from `y.scss` etc.

(Notice also how this avoids the separate `mv` of a static temporary file name, as discussed in comments.)

```
%.css: %.scss
    mym1.pl <$< >$@
%.php: %.phtml
    mym1.pl <$< >$@
```

This tells `make` how to create `m.z.css` from `m.z.scss`, `d.w.php` from `d.w.phtml`, etc. I'm guessing here that `mym1.pl` can handle both cases.

(Notice also the refactoring to avoid [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat).)

This does away with the somewhat mysterious `.m` and `.d` *suffixes* so you probably have to refactor the variables at the top of your `Makefile`.

Comment: After trying to stay with my original approach I eventually bit the bullet and refactored as you suggested, works and code is clean, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of creating the CSS targets I get this error:
>
> ```
> make: *** No rule to make target 'm.page.css', needed by 'all'.  Stop.
> ```

Your makefile provides exactly one rule by which `m.page.css` could be built or updated:

> ```
> %.css:  %.m %d
>     cat $< | mym1.pl >$@
>     rm $<
> ```

In order for that rule to apply, however, both of the prerequisites, expressed as `%.m` and `%d` [sic] need to exist or be able to be built.  There are problems with both.

The former in this case represents a file `m.page.m`.  This apparently does not already exist, but you have a rule by which it could be built from `m.page.scss`.  Except you don't *have* an `m.page.scss` or any rule to build one.  The corresponding root source file is actually `page.sccs`.

The latter prerequisite, `%d`, would have an analogous problem, but it doesn't even get that far because you have omitted a period from the prerequisite name (should be `%.d`, not `%d`).

The rule quoted above is moreover bogus because it designates two prerequisites but only uses one.  That's not inherently wrong, but it does not do anything useful to serve you here.

Replacing your current pattern rules with these should help:

```
m.%.m:    %.scss
    echo "%define MOBILE" | cat - $< >tmp
    mv tmp $@

d.%.d:    %.scss
    echo "%define DESKTOP" | cat - $< >tmp
    mv tmp $@

%.css:  %.m
    cat $< | mym1.pl >$@
    rm $<

%.css:  %.d
    cat $< | mym1.pl >$@
    rm $<
```

Comment: Have worked on this approach along the lines of your suggestions and got it to work but as per previous comments it was messy so ended up changing approach to that suggested by @tripleee, thanks for your help